# Javascript: Open other page and proceed with actions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate, window.open

I am currently working on a one-page design with different subpages. I've had some troubles with linking anchors to the subpages so I tried to solve it with a little bit of JavaScript.

My basic idea is to redirect to assign the following on click function to the link, which

1. Opens the target page
2. Scrolls to the target ID

   ```
    function scroll_to() {
    window.open('index.html#somepage') 
    setTimeout(1000);
    var elem = document.getElementById('#id');
    var topPos = elem.offset().top;
    animate({scrollTop:topPos});
    }
   ```

It opens the target page, but then stops proceeding with the other actions (after the timeout, which I inserted to make sure the target page is ready to be scrolled on).

Can anyone help me out? I also have tried something different, e.g. opening another page after the time-out but nothing happens, as if the code can't proceed on on a different page.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a js file that run in the new opened page.

so, in this html `index.html#somepage` you need a js whit:ù

```
window.onload = function() {//do something}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this execute the function everytime this page is loaded? (even when it is not opened by the onClick function from the link?

Comment: Yes, so you can use this way:§
when scroll_to() is called inside this function put localStorage.scrollTo = true; and when window.onload in the opened page make an if that check if the local storage scrollTo is true for prevent the scroll each time the page is loaded